# How to find the index of the largest numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x

In a list, there might be several largest numbers. I want to get the indices of them all.
For example:

**In the list a=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]

The indices of the largest numbers are 4,5,6**

I know the question is easy for most of people, but please be patient to answer my question.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [156]: a=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]

In [157]: m = max(a)

In [158]: [i for i,num in enumerate(a) if num==m]
Out[158]: [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create a variable maxNum = 0

2) loop through list if a[i] > maxNum : maxNum = a[i]

3)loop through list a second time now if a[i] == maxNum: print(i)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]
b = max(a)
[x for x, y in enumerate(a) if y == b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `heapq`:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter
a=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]
largest = heapq.nlargest(3, enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))
indices, _ = zip(*largest)
```

Of course, if your list is already sorted (your example list is), it may be as simple as doing

```
indices = range(len(a) - 3, len(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist=[1,2,3,3,3]
maxVal=max(mylist)
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
    if(mylist[i]==maxVal):
        print i
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The author asked to print out the all the  indices of the max value in the array. And my code exactly provides that. Please be clear why does my post does not provide the answer.

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. So, despite the question is of low quality, your answer should never consist of plain code snippet - consider adding at least one-two sentences of its explanation.